# Maximum value of function without root of derivative

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Given the function

$$f(x) = \frac{x^{p-k} a_k}{\sum_{i=0}^p (x^{p-i} a_i)}$$

, where $x>0, a_i>0$ for all $i$. $p>0, k=1,...,p-1$ are integers,

is it possible to characterize the maximum value of $f$ for a given $k$? Can we say anything about the maximum of $f$ at all?

In particular, is there a closed-form expression for the maximum value of $f$, or if not, can we find the maximum value of $f$ as the root of a polynomial or algebraic equation (in terms of $p,k,a_i$ for all $i$, i.e. eliminating $x$)?

I note the usual method of differentiating wrt $x$, solving the resulting equation yields only one root, the solution of

$$\sum_{i=0}^p (i-k)x^{p-i}a_i = 0$$

However, that root cannot be obtained in closed-form, so doesn't help us say anything about the maximum value of $f$. I am interested in whether that max $f$ can be calculated, e.g. directly as the root of a polynomial, without first calculating the $x$ which maximizes it.

Comment: You should flip the indexes. Your ratio is a polynomial that divides one of its terms.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : I agree that it is weird to sum all these polynomials in reverse order.  I imagine there is some sequential process acting on successive initial segments of a long sequence of $a_i$s which is the source of the weird ordering.

Comment: @EricTowers: there is no point keeping the reversal to solve the problem.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, the problem could be defined as finding the minimum of $1/f(x)$. But can you show how it's any easier to find the minimum from writing a summation 1/x^n terms, than Eric Towers did for the presentation given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgraded from "sometimes yes" to "frequently yes".  I suspect there may be failure for certain parameter combinations, but haven't found such a combination after some searching over generic systems with small $p$.  (OP observes that a promising potential obstruction, an inseparable $r(x)$ was shown impossible in a previous Question, the answer to which used Descartes's rule of signs to argue that there was exactly one positive root of $r$.)

---

I don't have a full solution, but I do have a "sometimes yes".

You want to maximize the ratio of a monomial of degree less than $p$ to a polynomial of degree $p$ with the constraint that a different polynomial of degree $p$ is zero.

Let's give a concrete example.  Suppose $a_0 = a_1 = a_5 = 1$ and $a_i = 0$ otherwise.  (Stricly, this does not match the specification of the problem, since we have $a_2 = a_3 = a_4 \not > 0$, but making these coefficients positive utterly obscures the illustrated operations.  Alternatively, reducing the degree to "squeeze out" these zero coefficients yields an example of too low degree to be illustrative.  Consequently, we proceed with this minor violation of the specification.)  Then, with $k = 1$, you want to maximize
$$  \frac{x^4}{1+x^4+x^5}  $$
and we know this maximum is attained (using your result from the first derivative) when $x^5 - 4 = 0$.

We can treat this as an attempt at reduction of
$$  \frac{x^4}{1+x^4+x^5}  $$
with the relation $x^5 = 4$.  This gives the sequence of reductions \begin{align*}
\frac{x^4}{1+x^4+x^5} &\rightarrow \frac{x^4}{5+x^4} \ \left[ {}\cdot \frac{x}{x} \right]  \\
    &= \frac{x^5}{5x+x^5}  \\
    &\rightarrow \frac{4}{4 + 5x}
\end{align*}

If you plot the first, second and fourth of these (the second and the third give the same curve), you see that they intersect at the maximal point of $\frac{x^4}{1+x^4+x^5}$.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(If we continue, reducing and multiplying by "fancy forms of $1$" (e.g. $x/x$), we get the second and fourth expressions forever.  If we had more nonzero $a_i$, we would get more expressions in the cycle.)

As a happy coincidence, we can take the function given by the fourth expression
$$  y = \frac{4}{4+5x}  $$
and solve for $x$.  (We should expect to be able to do this if any of our rational functions has small degrees in the numerator and denominator and, in very rare coincidences, otherwise.)
$$  x = \frac{4(1-y)}{5y}  $$
Now plug that into either other expression.  (It doesn't matter which one, we get the same result with either choice, but the amount of work to get there varies.)
$$ y = \frac{x^4}{5+x^4} = \frac{256(y-1)^4}{625 \left( 5+\frac{256(y-1)^4}{625y^4} \right) y^4}  \text{.}  $$
Solving the resulting polynomial for $y$,
$$  3381 y^5 - 1280 y^4 + 2560 y^3 - 2560 y^2 + 1280 y- 256 = 0  \text{,}  $$
yields the maximum value for the expression in question as its one real (positive) root.  (It's
$$  \frac{2^{8/5}}{5+2^{8/5}} = 0.37744{\dots}  \text{.)}  $$

Admittedly, this method relies on a couple of happy coincidences.  But, when it works, it works.

---

There is some theory in play here.  Suppose we wish to maximize the rational function
$$  \frac{n(x)}{d(x)}  $$
in $\Bbb{R}(x)$, the ring of rational expressions with positive coefficients.  Here, $n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree in the interval $[1,p-1]$ and $d(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $p$.  We can work in the ring $\Bbb{R}[x,y]$ by rewriting as
$$  y \cdot d(x) - n(x) = 0  \text{.}  $$
This generates an ideal in $\Bbb{R}[x,y]$ (of all polynomials in $x$ and $y$ which are $0$ when $y \cdot d(x) - n(x)$ is and possibly at additional points in the plane).

We have the relation (from solving for the stationary point using the derivative) $r(x) = 0$ for some polynomial of degree $p$.  When we quotient by $\langle r(x) \rangle$, we get the quotient ideal
$$  I = \frac{\langle y \cdot d(x) - n(x) \rangle}{\langle r(x) \rangle} \subset \frac{\Bbb{R}[x,y]}{\langle r(x) \rangle}    \text{.}  $$
(The reduction steps above move from element to element of this quotient ideal.)

We would like to know if there is a polynomial in $y$ in $I$.  That is, we want to know if $I \cap \Bbb{R}[y]$ is nonempty.  If it is, since $\Bbb{R}$ is a field, $\Bbb{R}[y]$ is a [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain), and $I \cap \Bbb{R}[y]$ is generated by a single polynomial of least degree in the intersection.  This polynomial is the one requested in the Question.

Whether the intersection is nonempty can be determined by constructing a reduced [Groebner basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) of $\{ y \cdot d(x) - n(x), r(x) \}$ with the variable ordering $x, y$.  Such a Groebner basis will have an initial segment of polynomials in $x$ and $y$ and a terminal segment of polynomials in only $y$.  If the terminal segment is empty, the intersection is empty.  If the terminal segment is nonempty, the polynomial (as observed above, there is only one if the basis is reduced) is the one sought in the Question.

I don't know of any simple to perform test on $d$, $n$, and $r$ that will tell if this process will produce a polynomial in $y$.  The best that can be said is that this is a finite process guaranteed to complete and either find such a polynomial or fail to do so.  And if it fails to do so, that constitutes a proof that the intersection is empty.

One down side: there is little reason to believe that the degree of the polynomial in $y$ is low.  So there may be a solution that is valid in principle, but not computationally useful in practice.

---

As an explicit example of the Groebner basis method, take
$p = 6$, \begin{align*}
a_0 &= 3  \\
a_1 &= 5  \\
a_2 &= 1  \\
a_3 &= 17  \\
a_4 &= 1/2  \\
a_5 &= 31415/10000  \\
a_6 &= 2  \\
\end{align*}

Then the generators for the ideal $\langle d(x)y-n(x), r(x) \rangle$ are
\begin{align*}
k&=1 :& \left\langle \left(3 x^6+5 x^5+x^4+17 x^3+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{6283 x}{2000}+2\right) y-5 x^5,-3 x^6+x^4+34 x^3+\frac{3 x^2}{2}+\frac{6283 x}{500}+10 \right\rangle  \\
k&=2 :& \left\langle \left(3 x^6+5 x^5+x^4+17 x^3+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{6283 x}{2000}+2\right)y-x^4,-6 x^6-5 x^5+17 x^3+x^2+\frac{18849 x}{2000}+8 \right\rangle  \\
k&=3 :& \left\langle \left(3 x^6+5 x^5+x^4+17 x^3+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{6283 x}{2000}+2\right)y-17 x^3,-9 x^6-10 x^5-x^4+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{6283 x}{1000}+6 \right\rangle  \\
k&=4 :& \left\langle \left(3 x^6+5 x^5+x^4+17 x^3+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{6283 x}{2000}+2\right) y-\frac{x^2}{2},-12 x^6-15 x^5-2 x^4-17 x^3+\frac{6283 x}{2000}+4 \right\rangle  \\
k&=5 :& \left\langle \left(3 x^6+5 x^5+x^4+17 x^3+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{6283 x}{2000}+2\right) y-\frac{6283 x}{2000},-15 x^6-20 x^5-3 x^4-34 x^3-\frac{x^2}{2}+2 \right\rangle  \\
\end{align*}

Then using software to compute the Groebner bases using [elimination order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order#Elimination_order) ("lexdeg") we obtain the intersection ideals generated by the following:
\begin{align*}
k&=1 :& \left\langle 6138919015691079101529909209 y^6 + 2240405737753079415080897600 y^5 + 2081288581773650633878448000 y^4 + 238526373367786274502272000 y^3 - 64178056050703070776320000 y^2 - 163849551050401173321216000 y + 16000000000000000000000000 \right\rangle  \\
k&=2 :& \left\langle 6138919015691079101529909209 y^6+24739953076838110263114400 y^5+51094587902899422481781600 y^4+6732609568373285915340800 y^3+311050507863667790521600 y^2-8437109555351601157120 y-503316480000000000000 \right\rangle  \\
k&=3 :& \left\langle 6138919015691079101529909209 y^6-48819875712398124502379959200 y^5+151515077917012145269151616000 y^4-233975590117705242864677760000 y^3+191217615919976688245964800000 y^2-79039391285214164366714880000 y+12973391069921280000000000000 \right\rangle  \\
k&=4 :& \left\langle 6138919015691079101529909209 y^6+165028651650769632816068000 y^5+30361674369652778778480000 y^4+1372726062269954208000000 y^3+26035777224447040000000 y^2-726516916346880000000 y-17694720000000000000 \right\rangle  \\
k&=5 :& \left\langle 6138919015691079101529909209 y^6+3417936660792812819590016586 y^5+1348264686861445252149012055 y^4+269194306035102012141441740 y^3-114653545686145512007201545 y^2-67879726900560328135508534 y+4982959727226654732330489 \right\rangle  \\
\end{align*}

Inspecting the polynomial for $k =1$, it has two real, positive roots.  The zero at $y = 0.318{\dots}$ is the maximum you want corresponding to $x = 2.37{\dots}$.  The zero at $y = 0.0965{\dots}$ corresponds to a local minimum at $x = -0.496{\dots}$.  Of course, nothing in the above restricts to $x > 0$ or to $y > 0$, so even if there is a polynomial in the intersection, you may have some filtering of its positive real roots to find the one that corresponds to the maximum.

---

For small $p$, we can generate the generic polynomial in $y$.  For $p = 1$, there are no valid choices of $k$.

\begin{align*}
p = 2 &, k = 1 &:& a_2 \left(a_1^2 y^2-4 a_0 a_2 y^2-2 a_1^2 y+a_1^2\right)  \\
\\
p = 3 &, k = 1 &:& a_3 \left( \left(4 a_1^3a_3- a_1^2a_2^2-18 a_0 a_1 a_2 a_3 +4 a_0 a_2^3+27 a_0^2 a_3^2\right) y^3 + \left(-12 a_1^3a_3 +2 a_1^2a_2^2 +18 a_0 a_1a_2 a_3 \right) y^2 + \left(12 a_1^3 a_3-a_1^2 a_2^2\right) y-4 a_1^3 a_3 \right)  \\
p = 3 &, k = 2 &:& a_3 \left( \left(4 a_1^3a_3 -a_1^2a_2^2 -18 a_0 a_1 a_2 a_3 +4 a_0 a_2^3+27 a_0^2 a_3^2\right) y^3 + \left(-12 a_0 a_2^3+2 a_1^2 a_2^2+18 a_0 a_1 a_2a_3 \right) y^2+\left(12 a_0 a_2^3-a_1^2 a_2^2\right) y - 4 a_0 a_2^3 \right)
\end{align*}

Of course, we now get a criterion for the polynomial in $y$ to have degree less than $p$ : make the leading coefficient zero.  For instance, in the $p = 3$, either $k$ cases, taking (a random example) $a_0 = a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 5/32$, and $a_3 = (-76+14\sqrt{34})/3456$ makes both polynomials in $y$ quadratic.  We can work to find simple criteria for this reduction in degree.  For instance, this can only happen if $a_3 \in \left( 0, a_2^2 / (3 a_1) \right]$.

Comment: Just the kind of answer I was looking for. I understood the process you followed for the example, and for the theory (second half) there are a few new concepts which I'll need to take a few days to really understand.

Comment: I was wondering though, if you could provide a more motivating example. In the given example, the solution is easily obtained by substitution as (what you later call) $r(x)=0$ can be solved analytically for the root. A harder case where substitution wouldn't work would be appreciated. There is no need to carry through the algebra to the end, a single algebraic $f(y)=0$, or even $y=g(x)$ where $x=h(y)$, is fine.

Comment: @MobeusZoom : An example of the Groebner Basis method added.  As a warning: throwing a couple of polynomials into a Groebner basis calculation is similar to throwing them into a blender -- what comes out is a vigorous mangling of the inputs.  I'm not going to pretend to manually perform the (potentially very long) sequence of substitutions and reductions in that step.  Also, even when the coefficients of $n$, $d$, and $r$ are small, the Groebner basis will likely have far larger coefficients.

Comment: @MobeusZoom : As an aside, the given example was chosen essentially "at random".  That all five choices of $k$ gave a nonempty intersection is a little surprising.  I'll do additional testing.  I would expect that there are some choices of parameter that give empty intersections (i.e., where all GBs have all basis elements dependent on $x$), but perhaps these are rarer than I think.

Comment: Your demo polynomial is not of the specified form.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : Which criterion do you believe is violated?

Comment: @YvesDaoust : All constraints verified satisfied.  You'll have to be vastly more specific.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : "Given the function ... where ... for".  The clarity of your claim only seems to be decreasing.

Comment: Compare to your seventh sentence.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : Ah.  NEver would have seen that from your far too vague initial observation.  I was scouring the polynomial added in the last 24 hours and not seeing anything that matched your observation.
Also, I'm not going to change the example.  Bringing it into conformance with the specification makes it useless.  I will note and explain why it is in variance.

Comment: @EricTowers: thanks for updating with an excellent example!  Could you provide the code for it? I'd very much like to do some testing myself, and would be interested to hear any of your results. Did you identify any examples where the method failed? (If I'm not mistaken [you showed earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4041104/prove-properties-of-sum-function) that with this function a repeated root of r(x) is impossible.) Does the polynomial appear to be always of order $p$?

Comment: @MobeusZoom : The code will not be of much use to you since Mathematica has a `GroebnerBasis` command.  I used `a[x_] := Piecewise[{{3, x == 0}, {5, x == 1}, {1, x == 2}, {17, x == 3}, {1/2, x == 4}, {31415/10000, x == 5}, {2, x == 6}}, 0];`  ,   `system[p_, k_] := {Sum[x^(p - i) a[i], {i, 0, p}] y - x^(p - k) a[k], Sum[(i - k) x^(p - i) a[i], {i, 0, p}]}`  ,  `systems = system[6, #] & /@ Range[1, 6 - 1]`  ,  `GroebnerBasis[#, {x, y}, x] & /@ systems`.

Comment: @MobeusZoom : Since $0-k$ and $a_0$ are both nonzero, the degree of $r(x)$ is always $p$.

Comment: @MobeusZoom : I've been poking around at the general systems for small $p$.  When $ p =1$, there are no valid choices of $k$.  When $p = 2$, the roots of the $y$ polynomial are $$k = 1: y_{\text{crit}} =  \frac{-a_1^2 \pm 2 a_1 \sqrt{a_0 a_2}}{4a_0 a_2 - a_1^2}$$.  These are both positive when $a_0 < a_1^2 / (4 a_2)$.

Comment: @MobeusZoom : ... For example, with $(a_0, a_1, a_2) = (1,3,2)$, the root at $y = 0.514{\dots}$ corresponds to the local maximum at $x = \sqrt{2}$ and the root at $y = 17.485{\dots}$ corresponds to a local minimum at $x = - \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @EricTowers Thanks for the code. So it seems (if only empirically so far) that the method successfully generates a polynomial in $y$ where a maximum exists (that is, under the conditions mentioned in the OP: $p>0, k \in [1,\dots,p-1], a_i>0$ for all $i$), and that this polynomial is of degree $p$. You may consider whether even "frequently yes" could be upgraded :)

Comment: @EricTowers Do you think it'd be possible to obtain the coefficients of the polynomials in $y$ symbolically from Mathematica (as functions of $a_0,\dots,a_p$), at least for small $p$ such as $p=3$ or $p=4$?

Comment: @MobeusZoom : Added $p=2$ and $p=3$ generic polynomials in $y$.  Adding the $p=4$ polynomials is more work than I'm undertaking for a random internet stranger's random problem.

Comment: @EricTowers of course it'd be unreasonable for you to do undertake that by hand and if you did so for even $p=3$ I'm very grateful. In any case it seems the question is answered. Under the conditions stated the polynomial in $y$ can be generated as you illustrated. General forms seem obtainable (if a lot of work). Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @EricTowers I presume you did the general calculation for $p=3$ by hand rather than by Mathematica. I'll be looking into the possibility of doing the algebra for $p=4$ and higher using some kind of symbolic computation software (e.g. [1](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/33051/compute-groebner-basis-of-an-ideal-that-includes-parameters/), [2](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/26748/groebner-basis-computation-with-symbolic-constants/)) and if you have any advice on doing that with Mathematica, since you seem experienced, it'd be very welcome

Comment: @MobeusZoom : For the general case, I have used Mathematica to verify the results for $p = 2, 3$.  `genSystem[p_, k_] := {Sum[x^(p - i) a[i], {i, 0, p}] y - x^(p - k) a[k], Sum[(i - k) x^(p - i) a[i], {i, 0, p}]}` , `genSystems[p_] := (genSystem[p, #] & /@ Range[1, p - 1])` , `GroebnerBasis[#, {x, y}, x] & /@ genSystems[2]` , `GroebnerBasis[#, {x, y}, x] & /@ genSystems[3] (* newline *)  Assuming[{a[0] > 0, a[1] > 0, a[2] > 0, a[3] > 0}, Factor[#] & /@ % ]`.

Comment: @MobeusZoom : One warning: the computation time seems to grow approximately exponentially in $p$.  This is entirely reasonable given that all known methods for computing Groebner Bases require (at least) exponential time.  The form {linear in y with coefficients in x, polynomial in x} may be nice enough to get "better than worst case" behaviour from various Groebner Basis implementations, but you should still expect rapidly increasing time cost.